# Formula - Multiply Date Field by Picklist value (Number of Weeks) - Needs to be editable

Tags: formula, picklist, date, field-update

Trying to create in Process Builder. When a Lead Time is selected from a picklist then The **Contract_Date__c** is populated with **Order Received Date** * **Lead Time**

So if you have a Contract Date of today and the lead time is 8 weeks then the out put would be today + 56 days.

```
[Opportunity].Order_Received_Date__c + 
ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].Lead_Time__c,

"1",  7, 

"2",  14, 

"3", 21, 


"4",  28, 

"5",  35,

"6", 42,

"7", 49,

"8",  56,0)
```

I've tried CASE and ISPICKVAL but I keep receiving the below error

> ERROR: The formula expression is invalid: Field Opportunity is a
>   picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain
>   functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just convert the value to a number:

```
[Opportunity].Order_Received_Date__c + (VALUE(TEXT([Opportunity].Lead_Time__c)) * 7)
```

Or, you can use CASE:

```
Opportunity].Order_Received_Date__c + 
CASE([Opportunity].Lead_Time__c, 
"1", 7, 
"2", 14, 
"3", 21, 
"4", 28, 
"5", 35,
"6", 42,
"7", 49,
"8", 56, 0)
```